# Does it have APN GCM push notification wrapper Java API?

Tags: java, android, ios

Currently I am working on a server side project to send push notification to apple and android device on our mobile app.

we have user's device id for both iOS/Android.

I am looking for a Java universal API can support both of them so I can do batch job to send message to all devices

any one can  suggest a good one.

I use Java.

BTW, I also use Amazon SQS to queue the message, if there is a API can integrate with SQS, that will be better